# Angular tutorial Step 4 :: Assigning default value to select issue

Tags: angularjs

I am going thru AngularJs tutorial. In step 4 http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04 instead of hard coded Select tag I created a JavaScript object just to test.

This is the javascript code I added to controller.js

```
 $scope.sortOptions = [{
        "optionValue": "name",
        "desc": "Alphabetical"
    }, {
        "optionValue": "age",
        "desc": "Newest"
    }];
```

Now $scope.orderProp = "age" is not working. (which suppose to set default value for the select). I want to know what is issue here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Khuzema/m6Z5Z/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `ng-options` attribute on the `<select>` to create the `<option>` entries, like this:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" 
        ng-options="option.optionValue as option.desc for option in sortOptions">                        
</select>
```

The `option.optionValue as option.desc for option in sortOptions` corresponds to:

- iterate over the `sortOptions` array and assign each item to a `option` variable
- set the label of each `<option>` as `option.desc`
- set the value of each `<option>` as `option.optionValue`

More information about this here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/m6Z5Z/2/