# Setting 'select' as default value in dropdown using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to make a simple dropdown using angularjs and want to invoke a function when the dropdown value is changed. Only when the dropdown selection is 'A', i want to display some other elements(say 'hello') in my page. 
Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gkJve/932/.

Html

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select id="sel" class="input-block-level" ng-model="list_category" ng-options="obj.name for obj in list_categories" ng-change="DropDownChange()">    
        <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="showdiv">
      Hello
    </div>
   <div>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    $scope.showdiv=false;
function Ctrl($scope) {  
    $scope.list_categories =  [{
            id: 'id1',
            name: 'A'
        }, {
            id: 'id2',
            name: 'B'
        }];       
      $scope.DropDownChange = function() {
      $scope.showdiv = angular.equals($scope.list_category.name,'A');
  }
}
```

Result - 'Hello' is displayed when 'A' is selected and hidden when 'B' is selected. But the problem is, if I select 'A' and then change my selection to 'Select', 'hello' is still displayed. I think its because 'select' is not one of my model data value the comparison is failing. Is there any other way to make this work without adding 'select' to my model data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular tutorial Step 4 :: Assigning default value to select issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449711/angular-tutorial-step-4-assigning-default-value-to-select-issue)

Comment: @RohitArora - The question you have mentioned is not related as it doesn't talk about ng-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

```
<div ng-show="list_category.name == 'A'">
```

Comment: Such a simple solution! Thank you. I thought list_category.name is not updated with 'select' value and that is why the comparison failed. But now I couldn't understand why my code wouldn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: because you use the ng-change at that time list_category set empty.. so only not working

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    $scope.showdiv=false;
function Ctrl($scope) {  
    $scope.list_categories =  [{
            id: 'id1',
            name: 'A'
        }, {
            id: 'id2',
            name: 'B'
        }];       
      $scope.DropDownChange = function() {
     if($scope.list_category == null || $scope.list_category == "")
     {
        $scope.showdiv = false;
     }
     else{
        $scope.showdiv = angular.equals($scope.list_category.name,'A');
     }

  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03dczcyb/)